# Unable to get isolated scope directive from parent controller

Tags: angularjs

My problem is unable to get this input value from ParentController. If anybody knows please update. Thanks in advance.

My HTML :

```
   <div ng-controller="ParentController">
         <my-dir add-Id="123" custom-data="getData()"></my-dir>// This is my directive
   </div>
```

My directive :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope:{
      addId: "=",
      customData : "&"
    },
    controller:['$scope', function($scope){
        console.log('non template directive controller:',$scope.title);
    }],
    template : <div><input ng-model="myValue"></div>
  };
});
```

Comment: It should be `add-id` not `addId` in the markup

Comment: hi PSL.. I did like that only.. Just sample I gave.

Comment: Can you post a working example..., Which input value you are not able to get?

Comment: I have getData() method under ParentController.  In this method I need ng-model="myValue". This model value present in directive html.

Comment: `ng-model="myValue"` is in the isolated scope of the directive, you cannot access it in the parentController. What is `callBack` ? what is `customData`? Can you post a plnkr

Comment: My program is biggest module. I tried to post my problem. So there is no way to access isolated scope data from parent controller.

Comment: That is what 2-way binding is for.. SO that you can share data between isolated scoped directive and it s parent

Comment: for me unable to get directive scope data in controller. This is problem

Comment: We cannot see what you are doing.. You just have your directive and you have not presented your controller code. And the shared variables does not match. I really have no clue on what you are trying to do.. :

Comment: You have not defined a property named "title" in your isolated scope.